# Split list items into columns and append to new list

Tags: python, list

I have a list where each element is a long string of characters with same length:

```
['KLGNVAGELQPFAPSED', 'MPDNVSFELQPPASJED', 'YYLNVSFEDQPPAPMED']
```

What I want to do is produce a new list, where each element is a string of characters in from same position of first list. You can also imagine same first list as this:

```
KLGNVAGELQPFAPSED
MPDNVSFELQPPASJED
YYLNVSFEDQPPAPMED
```

so I want new list to have elements from corresponding columns in first list, like this:

```
['KMY', 'LPY', 'GDL' 'NNN', ...]
```

What I tried is this:

```
for i in sub1:
   for j in i:
      pos.append(j)
   pos.append('\n')
```

But then I can't manage to separate everything into separate lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `zip` the elements of the list together and then join the tuples as strings:

```
new_list = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*old_list)] # KMY, LPY, GDL, ...
```

Comment: Works just as needed! Never heard about this * character. Thanks.

Comment: @estranged Yeah, basically the `*` unpacks the list as arguments for the function.

Comment: Please mark as answer with the check mark beside my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> l = ['KLGNVAGELQPFAPSED', 'MPDNVSFELQPPASJED', 'YYLNVSFEDQPPAPMED']
>>> map(''.join,zip(*l))
['KMY', 'LPY', 'GDL', 'NNN', 'VVV', 'ASS', 'GFF', 'EEE', 'LLD', 'QQQ', 'PPP', 'FPP', 'AAA', 'PSP', 'SJM', 'EEE', 'DDD']
```

Do note that `map` is faster than a list-comp wherever there is no need of an `lambda` function.

```
$ python -m timeit "[''.join(i) for i in zip(*['KLGNVAGELQPFAPSED', 'MPDNVSFELQPPASJED', 'YYLNVSFEDQPPAPMED'])]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.54 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "map(''.join,zip(*['KLGNVAGELQPFAPSED', 'MPDNVSFELQPPASJED', 'YYLNVSFEDQPPAPMED']))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 usec per loop
```

You can check out more about the speed difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

> map may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're NOT
>   making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map
>   and a listcomp). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases and
>   most (not all) pythonistas consider them more direct and clearer.